# Can we upload file to firebase with file extension in flutter(.pdf or .jpg)?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The main reason for my question is that when I normally upload an image or file, the URL looks like this..

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/petpulz-93d6f.appspot.com/o/records%2Fpost_1683391240123?alt=media&token=3fa03aa4-78f4-4329-bacf-5793072055e1
```

Because of URLs like these, when I fetch, reopen, or download the file, I cannot identify its file type.
Is there a way to upload files to Firebase and add the relevant file extension at the end of the URL, such as **.pdf**, **.jpg**, or **.doc**

**upload firebase storage and upload downloadurl to firebase firestore**

```
  Future<void> _uploadFiles() async {
    final postID = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    final List<String> downloadUrls = [];

    for (final file in _selectedFiles) {
      final ref = storage.ref().child("user").child("post_$postID");
      final uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

      final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});

      final downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      downloadUrls.add(downloadUrl);
    }

    await firestore.collection("users")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .set({
    "username" : title.text,
      'fileUrls': FieldValue.arrayUnion(downloadUrls),
    });

    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the extension, like `.child("post_$PostID.jpg")`?

Comment: actually, i didn't try this. Because I cannot add specific extension, some time can be .pdf , .doc , .jpg  like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the extension of the file using [path](https://pub.dev/packages/path) package:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

...

for (final file in _selectedFiles) {
  // add this the get the extension
  final fileExtension = p.extension(file.path);  

  // append the extension to the child name
  final ref = storage.ref().child("user").child("post_$postID$fileExtension");
  final uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

  final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});

  final downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  downloadUrls.add(downloadUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. It's worked when added you code change the firebase storage file name 'post_1683454539414..jpg' to this but url is still same "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/petpulz-93d6f.appspot.com/o/records%2Fpost_1683454539414..jpg?alt=media&token=a047c6bb-e87d-4f8f-92cf-746fff5f0599 "actually i want add that to url.

Comment: You are welcome. The URL now contains JPEG (there are two dots, I corrected the answer to remove the dot since the extension contains it). The first part of the URL is fix for the storage and you add the last part with `child(...)`.

Comment: Actually, I achieved what I wanted because of your support. With your help, I was able to upload a file extension to the middle of a URL, and then I wrote a code to extract it from the middle of the URL. here is the code to get file extension from middle of url "  final fileExtension = file.path.split('.').last.split('?').first; " Thank you so much for your support!!!

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.